# Property not found on View Model

Tags: c#, xamarin, model-view-controller

I have these view:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,24,30,24" Spacing="10">
  <syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackLayout>
             <Label Text="{Binding Text}"/>
          </StackLayout>
       </DataTemplate>
  </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
</syncfusion:SfListView>
```

And it's C# code:

```
public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    ItemsViewModel _viewModel;

    public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _viewModel.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

Here the model:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure why but with this view model:

```
public class ItemsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Item _selectedItem;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; }
    public Command AddItemCommand { get; }
    public Command<Item> ItemTapped { get; }

    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Contacts by David Zomada";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

        ItemTapped = new Command<Item>(OnItemSelected);

        AddItemCommand = new Command(OnAddItem);
    }

    async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Items.Clear();
            var items = await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true);
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        SelectedItem = null;
    }

    public Item SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
            OnItemSelected(value);
        }
    }

    private async void OnAddItem(object obj)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(NewItemPage));
    }

    async void OnItemSelected(Item item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;

        // This will push the ItemDetailPage onto the navigation stack
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(ItemDetailPage)}?{nameof(ItemDetailViewModel.ItemId)}={item.Id}");
    }
}
```

The compiler says: "Binding: Property "Text" not found on "Contacts.ViewModels.ItemsViewModel". (XFC0045)"

I'm clearly wrong but I don't get it where is my mistake? Could you help me to understand why my view is not binding correctly to the view model?

My understanding so far is that, if you bind an items source to a collection view when you use the binding to bind a property on a data template, the data get it's data from the items source.

Comment: You are not setting `Text` anywhere. Take for example you own code. You se the Title to something. And then you Bind your Title to your Title in XAML. You are not doing this with your Text.

Comment: Yes it is on the view ´<Label Text="{Binding Text}"/>´ Sorry I forgot to add the model

Comment: The title is define on the base model, also the INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: According to the model and the viewmodel the binding should be `Items.Text`. Try that.

Comment: It says the same. It looks like it's trying to find the item or the item property on the view model instead of understanding it has to look for it on its own items source

Comment: Can you try without `DataTemplate` above your `StackLayout`?

Comment: No, it forces u to use a 'DataTemplate' inside a ListView

Comment: I found my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

I was using this property on the view:

```
x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel"
```

It makes the compiler understand that it should find the property 'Text' on the view model, not on the model...

More info here: [Xamarin.Forms Compiled Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings)

Comment: it worked! thanks.. but it  reveals new error.. when clicking my Flyout menu, the app suddenly crashes.